# iPhone - SQLite Database Read

Tags: ios, database, xcode, sqlite

I'm trying to do a basic application.
My files list:

```
DatabaseClass.h and .m,
IDRGameAppDelegate.h and .m,
scoredb.sqlite,
ScoreViewController.h and .m, 
MainWindow.xib // Main Window
ScoreWindow.xib //Show Score Window
```

1.) my database is ;

```
CREATE TABLE "game" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"name" VARCHAR(32),"score" VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO "game" VALUES(1,'interclock','1.234');
INSERT INTO "game" VALUES(2,'dui','345');
INSERT INTO "game" VALUES(3,'reflex','987');
```

2-) i created DatabaseClass.h and DatabaseClass.m

DatabaseClass.h is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface DatabaseClass : NSObject {

    NSString *name;
    NSString *score;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *score;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n score:(NSString *)s;
@end
```

DatabaseClass.m is;

```
#import "DatabaseClass.h"
@implementation DatabaseClass
@synthesize name, score;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n score:(NSString *)s{
    self.name = n;
    self.score = s;
    return self;
}
@end
```

my IDRGameAppDelegate.h is;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
#import <sqlite3.h> // Import the SQLite database framework

@class IDRGameViewController , ScoreViewController  ;


@interface IDRGameAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet IDRGameViewController *viewController;
    IBOutlet ScoreViewController *scoreViewController;


    // Database variables
    NSString *databaseName;
    NSString *databasePath;

    // Array to store the animal objects
    NSMutableArray *scores; 
}

- (void)flipToScore;
- (void)scoreToMainBack;

-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase;
-(void) readScoreFromDatabase;

@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  IDRGameViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  ScoreViewController *scoreViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *scores;

@end
```

IDRGameAppDelegate.m is;

```
#import "IDRGameAppDelegate.h"
#import "IDRGameViewController.h"
#import "ScoreViewController.h"
#import "DatabaseClass.h"


@implementation IDRGameAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize scoreViewController;

@synthesize scores;



- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    // Setup some globals
    databaseName = @"scoredb.sqlite";

    // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Execute the "checkAndCreateDatabase" function
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

    // Query the database for all animal records and construct the "animals" array
    [self readScoreFromDatabase];

    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [scores release];
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{
    // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return;

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

    [fileManager release];
}


-(void) readScoreFromDatabase {
    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Init the animals Array
    scores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from game";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {



            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // Read the data from the result row

                NSString *aName =[NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                NSString *aScore =[NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

                //NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                //NSString *aScore = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];



                // Create a new animal object with the data from the database
                DatabaseClass *dbOBJ = [[DatabaseClass alloc] initWithName:aName score:aScore];

                // Add the animal object to the animals Array
                [scores addObject:dbOBJ];

                [dbOBJ release];
            }
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

}


- (void)flipToScore {


    ScoreViewController *aSecondView = [[ScoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScoreWindow" bundle:nil];
    [self setScoreViewController:aSecondView];
    [aSecondView release];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:window cache:YES];
    [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window addSubview:[scoreViewController view]];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)scoreToMainBack {



    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:window cache:NO];


    [scoreViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window addSubview:[viewController view]];

    [UIView commitAnimations];


    [scoreViewController release];
    scoreViewController = nil;

}
@end
```

ScoreViewController.h is;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ScoreViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *gameNameLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *gameScoreLabel;


}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *gameNameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *gameScoreLabel;

-(IBAction)refreshClick:(id)sender;

@end
```

and finally ScoreViewController.m is ;

```
#import "ScoreViewController.h"
#import "DatabaseClass.h"
#import "IDRGameAppDelegate.h"

@implementation ScoreViewController

@synthesize gameNameLabel,gameScoreLabel;


/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

-(IBAction)refreshClick:(id)sender {

    // Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller
    IDRGameAppDelegate *appDelegate = (IDRGameAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    DatabaseClass *dbOBJ = (DatabaseClass *)[appDelegate.scores objectAtIndex:0];



    gameNameLabel.text = [dbOBJ name];
    gameScoreLabel.text = [dbOBJ score];


}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Problem is: when I click to refreshButton program is locking and breaking, but I can't see an error.

Program is not working I didn't read and show database records. 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Why did you decide to stick directly with SQLite on the iPhone? After iPhone OS 3.0 is available to all iPhone users, i would recommend to make use of this database abstraction. It is quite easy to use and it prevents you to code a bunch of database access code.

On [Mike Swans](http://themikeswan.wordpress.com/2009/05/22/7/) blog is a useful introduction to core data, which may act as a starting point for your development.

As part of the iPhone reference documentation Apple published a [Core Data Tutorial for the iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH1-SW1) which covers the iPhone specific features.

I've used it in an application on my own and found it really time saving compared with the SQLite database code i had before.

Comment: Core Data comes with some performance baggage at seems.  For some apps, SQLite is the better choice.             http://inessential.com/2010/02/26/on_switching_away_from_core_data